# Spatial binning: Assigning points to next nearest Rainfall Station and MemoryError

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, geopandas

Credits to user @Rob Raymond for the original code.

Some alterations were done to input my dataset into the code.

Full dataset: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1D_k1iB5U-qE2FRRi4MYJ80815YW5FI5jpV0F1uy1ddk/edit?usp=sharing

Full Code: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1MaxH0od4IE_dKSNhbyQ9T5Z0sRMrqFfxVcT4xwkVllo/edit?usp=sharing

Snippet of Code:

df = df.dropna(subset=['Rainfall (mm)'])

gdf_rainfall = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
df_stations.merge(df, on="id")
.assign(
geometry=lambda d: gpd.points_from_xy(
d["location.longitude"], d["location.latitude"]
)
)
.drop(columns=["location.latitude", "location.longitude","Longitude","Latitude","Elevation"]),
crs=gdf_sg.crs,

Problem faced:

1. I intend to remove the Rainfall stations that have NaN (mm) of rainfall by using .dropna() to get the 'grid' to pull data from the next nearest rainfall station however, the map still has salients of empty 'Thiessen polygons' as shown in this output image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndAvW.pnghere
2. I require a finer pixelation of the map using 200x200m grids however, upon running STEP=200:

numpy.core._exceptions.MemoryError: Unable to allocate 5.67 GiB for an array with shape (4, 190093779) and data type int64

I'd like to know how to solve these problems thank you!

Comment: *Thiessen polygons (otherwise known as Voronoi polygons)* why are you trying to generate such a fine grained grid when what you want is Singapore weather stations organised by Voronoi polygons?

Comment: Apologies for the confusion Sir, I actually wanted to organise the Singapore-bounded 200x200m grids and assign them the nearest rainfall data but, if that rainfall station has NaN then, find and assign the 2nd nearest rainfall stn data that has rainfall value. I'll try to find a way around this by implementing the new code you've posted here. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: that's a different optimisation challenge....have added more details to end of answer.  you will need to be very thoughtful about how you approach this for an acceptable runtime and to avoid OOM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- there are two approaches to establishing an area covered by a weather station

  1. voronoi - establised optimised approaches
  2. divide up geometry into multiple boxes and associate boxes closed to required points
- have provided the approach to both.  The original answer was *lazy*.  Joined in rainfall data before establishing geometric areas.  Now establish geometric areas first, then after that associate rainfall data with a simple **pandas** merge (massively reduces amount more expensive `sjoin_nearest()` is doing

#### performance

```
%timeit station_polys(how="boxes", step=200)
16.9 s ± 1.4 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit station_polys(how="voronoi")
238 ms ± 30.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit station_polys(how="boxes", step=500)
2.54 s ± 13.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

#### get the data

```
import pandas as pd

# get data from google docs, the slow bit!!!!
df_ = pd.read_csv("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vS2ijDtnQnbjVhKO1n-9QcIWz2DTPIAxZ7GcIKzNdxEDlxDD6HOO0kITMBDv0sXOTuvLVDnBhx34DIv/pub?gid=186097297&single=true&output=csv")
```

#### solution

- runs quick on my laptop,  no memory issues

```
import shapely.geometry, shapely.ops
import geopandas as gpd
import numpy as np

gdf_sg = gpd.read_file(
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/yinshanyang/singapore/master/maps/0-country.geojson"
)
# Singapore bounday as a shapely multipolygon
sg = gdf_sg.dissolve()["geometry"].values[0]
utm = gdf_sg.estimate_utm_crs()

# restucture rainfall data to be long
# stack() by default dropna=True
df = (
    df_.set_index([c for c in df_.columns if c[0].isalpha()])
    .stack(dropna=False)
    .reset_index()
    .rename(columns={"level_5": "Date", 0: "Rainfall (mm)"})
    .drop(columns=["Station", "Longitude", "Latitude", "Elevation"])
)

df_stations = df_.loc[:, [c for c in df_.columns if c[0].isalpha()]]

# define function for performance testing...
def station_polys(how="boxes", step=200):
    if how == "voronoi":
        # generate a voronoi for all weather station points, clipped to Singapore boundary
        gdf_v = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
            geometry=[
                p.intersection(sg)
                for p in shapely.ops.voronoi_diagram(
                    shapely.geometry.MultiPoint(
                        gpd.points_from_xy(
                            df_stations["Longitude"], df_stations["Latitude"]
                        ),
                    ),
                ).geoms
            ],
            crs=gdf_sg.crs,
        ).to_crs(utm)

    elif how == "boxes":
        # number of meters
        STEP = step
        a, b, c, d = gdf_sg.to_crs(utm).total_bounds

        # create a grid for Singapore
        gdf_grid = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
            geometry=[
                shapely.geometry.box(minx, miny, maxx, maxy)
                for minx, maxx in zip(np.arange(a, c, STEP), np.arange(a, c, STEP)[1:])
                for miny, maxy in zip(np.arange(b, d, STEP), np.arange(b, d, STEP)[1:])
            ],
            crs=gdf_sg.estimate_utm_crs(),
        )
        gdf_v = gdf_grid.sjoin(gdf_sg.to_crs(utm)).drop(columns=["index_right", "name"])

    # associate voronoi or grid polygons with correct attributes (id)
    gdf_stations = (
        gpd.sjoin_nearest(
            gdf_v,
            gpd.GeoDataFrame(
                df_stations,
                geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(
                    df_stations["Longitude"], df_stations["Latitude"]
                ),
                crs=gdf_sg.crs,
            ).to_crs(utm),
        )
        .drop(columns=["index_right"])
        .dissolve("id")
    )
    return gdf_stations


gdf_stations = station_polys(how="voronoi", step=500)

# now associate geometry by station with rainfall data
gdf_rainfall = gpd.GeoDataFrame(pd.merge(df, gdf_stations, on="id"), crs=utm)

# let's plot what we have for a random date that has more stations in operation...
sample_date = np.random.choice(
    df.groupby("Date")["Rainfall (mm)"].sum().sort_values().index[-30:],
    1,
)[0]
gdf_rainfall.loc[lambda d: d["Date"].eq(sample_date)].explore(
    column="Rainfall (mm)",
    missing_kwds={
        "color": "lightgrey",
    },
    height=400,
    width=700,
)
```

#### sample output

[image]

#### update

*actually wanted to organise the Singapore-bounded 200x200m grids and assign them the nearest rainfall data but, if that rainfall station has NaN then, find and assign the 2nd nearest rainfall stn data that has rainfall value*

- have selected **voronoi** as approach
- have refactored code to enable generation of unique combinations of weather stations across multiple dates to be used (limit number of expensive polygon generation iterations)

```
import shapely.geometry, shapely.ops
import geopandas as gpd
import numpy as np

gdf_sg = gpd.read_file(
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/yinshanyang/singapore/master/maps/0-country.geojson"
)
# Singapore bounday as a shapely multipolygon
sg = gdf_sg.dissolve()["geometry"].values[0]
utm = gdf_sg.estimate_utm_crs()

# restucture rainfall data to be long
# stack() by default dropna=True
df = (
    df_.set_index([c for c in df_.columns if c[0].isalpha()])
    .stack(dropna=False)
    .reset_index()
    .rename(columns={"level_5": "Date", 0: "Rainfall (mm)"})
    .drop(columns=["Station", "Longitude", "Latitude", "Elevation"])
)

df_stations = df_.loc[:, [c for c in df_.columns if c[0].isalpha()]]

# make a grid of boxes covering Singapore
def make_grid(step=500):
    # number of meters
    STEP = step
    a, b, c, d = gdf_sg.to_crs(utm).total_bounds

    # create a grid for Singapore
    gdf_grid = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
        geometry=[
            shapely.geometry.box(minx, miny, maxx, maxy)
            for minx, maxx in zip(np.arange(a, c, STEP), np.arange(a, c, STEP)[1:])
            for miny, maxy in zip(np.arange(b, d, STEP), np.arange(b, d, STEP)[1:])
        ],
        crs=gdf_sg.estimate_utm_crs(),
    )
    return gdf_grid.sjoin(gdf_sg.to_crs(utm)).drop(columns=["index_right", "name"])


# define function for performance testing...
def station_polys(how="boxes", gdf_grid=None, ids=df_stations["id"].tolist()):
    df_stations_ = df_stations.merge(pd.Series(ids, name="id"), on="id")
    if how == "voronoi":
        # generate a voronoi for all weather station points, clipped to Singapore boundary
        gdf_v = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
            geometry=[
                p.intersection(sg)
                for p in shapely.ops.voronoi_diagram(
                    shapely.geometry.MultiPoint(
                        gpd.points_from_xy(
                            df_stations_["Longitude"], df_stations_["Latitude"]
                        ),
                    ),
                ).geoms
            ],
            crs=gdf_sg.crs,
        ).to_crs(utm)

    elif how == "boxes":
        gdf_v = gdf_grid

    # associate voronoi or grid polygons with correct attributes (id)
    gdf_stations = (
        gpd.sjoin_nearest(
            gdf_v,
            gpd.GeoDataFrame(
                df_stations_,
                geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(
                    df_stations_["Longitude"], df_stations_["Latitude"]
                ),
                crs=gdf_sg.crs,
            ).to_crs(utm),
        )
        .drop(columns=["index_right"])
        .dissolve("id")
    )
    return gdf_stations

def polys_for_combis(head=5, how="voronoi", gdf_grid=None):
    # have to be tuples so they are immutable and hashable for join
    # association between Date and combination of station ids
    s_combi = (
        df.dropna()
        .sort_values(["Date", "id"])
        .groupby("Date")["id"]
        .agg(tuple)
        .rename("combi")
    )

    # unique combinations, plus give them an id
    df_combi = pd.DataFrame({"combi": np.unique(s_combi)}).assign(
        combi_id=lambda d: d.index
    )
    # for testing use subset of combinations
    if head is not None:
        df_combi = df_combi.sample(n=head, random_state=44)

    # construct geometry for each combination of stations
    gdf_combi = pd.concat(
        [
            station_polys(how=how, ids=combi, gdf_grid=gdf_grid)
            .reset_index()
            .assign(combi_id=combi_id)
            for combi_id, combi in df_combi.set_index("combi_id")["combi"].iteritems()
        ]
    )

    # add date for combi and join in rainfall data
    gdf_rainfall = gdf_combi.merge(
        df_combi.merge(s_combi.reset_index(), on="combi").drop(columns=["combi"]),
        on="combi_id",
    ).merge(df, on=["id", "Date"])

    return gdf_rainfall
```

#### use it

```
gdf_stations = station_polys(how="voronoi")
# gdf_grid = make_grid(step=200)
# gdf_stations = station_polys(how="boxes", gdf_grid=gdf_grid)

# now associate geometry by station with rainfall data
gdf_rainfall = gpd.GeoDataFrame(pd.merge(df, gdf_stations, on="id"), crs=utm)

sample_date = "19801020" # staged, many NaNs and significant rainfall
plot_opts = dict(
    column="Rainfall (mm)",
    missing_kwds={
        "color": "lightgrey",
    },
    height=300,
    width=500,
)

m_nan = gdf_rainfall.loc[lambda d: d["Date"].eq(sample_date)].explore(**plot_opts)

# gdf_grid = make_grid(step=500)
# gdf_rainfall = polys_for_combis(how="boxes", gdf_grid=gdf_grid)
gdf_rainfall = polys_for_combis(how="voronoi", head=None)
m_no_nan = gdf_rainfall.loc[lambda d: d["Date"].eq(sample_date)].explore(**plot_opts)
```

#### output

```
from IPython.display import display, HTML

htmlmap = HTML(
    '<iframe srcdoc="{}" style="float:left; width: {}px; height: {}px; display:inline-block; width: 48%; margin: 0 auto; border: 2px solid black"></iframe>'
    '<iframe srcdoc="{}" style="float:right; width: {}px; height: {}px; display:inline-block; width: 48%; margin: 0 auto; border: 2px solid black"></iframe>'.format(
        m_nan.get_root().render().replace('"', "&quot;"),
        500,
        300,
        m_no_nan.get_root().render().replace('"', "&quot;"),
        500,
        300,
    )
)
display(htmlmap)
```

[image]

#### performance

```
%timeit -n 1 -r 1 polys_for_combis(how="voronoi", head=None)
3min 44s ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Yes, the processing time is indeed long for grids. I'll try to find other ways to handle the NaNs and force out the full map without null areas but, I'm definitely sticking with the voronoi method from now on as per your suggestion. Thank you so much for your kind help Sir!

Comment: found this an interesting challenge.... have updated answer,  getting a runtime <4mins using Voronoi