# Rainfall value not assigned fully to Grids on map

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas

Aim: To create a gridded map over Singapore with 200x200m gridsize and assign rainfall value to it from rainfall station dataset.

Dataset: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12Hhg9rMoCisFkMVeLIOajdCZ5nL2iFKgEERViww9nqg/edit#gid=1622479150

Code:

```
import requests, itertools, io
from pathlib import Path
import urllib
from zipfile import ZipFile
import fiona.drvsupport
import shapely.geometry
import webbrowser
import geopandas as gpd
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


### Print options
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 500)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)

### Load data
datafr = pd.read_csv('Comb_Daily_Pr_Special.csv')

### Station geodataframe
Stn_data = pd.DataFrame(datafr,columns=['id','Longitude','Latitude'])
Stn_data_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(Stn_data, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(Stn_data.Longitude,Stn_data.Latitude), crs='EPSG:3414')

### Re-make Precipitation array to [id,Date,Rainfall,Stn_name]
dfr = datafr.melt(id_vars=["id","Station","Longitude","Latitude","Elevation"], var_name="Date", value_name="Rainfall (mm)")

### Join gdf and dfr by 'id'
gdf = pd.merge(left=Stn_data_gdf, right=dfr, how='outer',on='id' )
gdf = gdf.sort_values(['Date','id']).reset_index().drop(columns=['index','Longitude_x', 'Latitude_x', 'Elevation','Longitude_y', 'Latitude_y'])
#df.to_csv('final.csv')

### Applying multi-indexing - FINAL Dataset for filling NaNs
gdf.set_index(['Date','id'], inplace=True)

### Drop rows with NaN
gdf = gdf.dropna().to_crs('4326').reset_index()

### Make grid of Singapore
url = "https://geo.data.gov.sg/planning-area-census2010/2014/04/14/kml/planning-area-census2010.zip"
f = Path.cwd().joinpath(urllib.parse.urlparse(url).path.split("/")[-1])
if not f.exists():
    r = requests.get(url, stream=True, headers={"User-Agent": "XY"})
    with open(f, "wb") as fd:
        for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=128):
            fd.write(chunk)
zfile = ZipFile(f)
zfile.extractall(f.stem)

fiona.drvsupport.supported_drivers['KML'] = 'rw'
gdf_sg = gpd.read_file([_ for _ in Path.cwd().joinpath(f.stem).glob("*.kml")][0], driver="KML") #Singapore area geometry

# Number of meters for grid
STEP = 200 #grid resolution size in nxn m
a, b, c, d = gdf_sg.to_crs(gdf_sg.estimate_utm_crs()).total_bounds #return minx, miny, maxx,maxy in this order to establish rectangular boundary

# Create a grid for Singapore
gdf_grid = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    geometry=[
        shapely.geometry.box(minx, miny, maxx, maxy)
        for minx, maxx in zip(np.arange(a, c, STEP), np.arange(a, c, STEP)[1:])
        for miny, maxy in zip(np.arange(b, d, STEP), np.arange(b, d, STEP)[1:])
    ],
    crs=gdf_sg.estimate_utm_crs(),
).to_crs(gdf_sg.crs)

# Restrict grid to only squares that intersect with Singapore geometry
gdf_grid = (
    gdf_grid.sjoin(gdf_sg)
    .pipe(lambda d: d.groupby(d.index).first())
    .set_crs(gdf_grid.crs)
    .drop(columns=["index_right"])
)

### Join the gdf_grid to gdf rainfall datas
gdf_grid_rainfall = gpd.sjoin_nearest(gdf_grid, gdf).drop(columns=['Description', 'index_right'])

### Visualize map with folium
sg_gridded_snap = gdf_grid_rainfall.loc[lambda d: d["Date"].eq("20211231")].explore("Rainfall (mm)", height=400, width=600)
output_file = "FINAL_map.html"
sg_gridded_snap.save(output_file)
webbrowser.open(output_file, new=2)  # open in new tab
```

Problems:

1. Are there any other ways for me to get a 200x200m gridmap without getting 'out of memory error'
2. I require all the grids to have an assigned rainfall value. For demonstration, I ran it on 1000x1000m grid to avoid memory error, but I instead obtain a gridded map with empty areas as shown:[image]

Thank you for your help!

Comment: how does this differ to solutions I already provided ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73636757/spatial-binning-assigning-points-to-next-nearest-rainfall-station-and-memoryerr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- as previously noted on this subject.  There are over 11k dates with rainfall data.  However there are only ~1k combinations of stations in operation across all of these dates
- hence an optimisation is to do geometry `join_nearest()` for combinations of stations rather than all dates.   This by the nature of how this is constructed will generate different polygons for weather stations that cover the whole of Singapore
- as previously noted - voronoi with perform far better that a grid,  this solution does work for both

#### data

```
import pandas as pd

# get data from google docs, the slow bit!!!!
df_ = pd.read_csv("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vS2ijDtnQnbjVhKO1n-9QcIWz2DTPIAxZ7GcIKzNdxEDlxDD6HOO0kITMBDv0sXOTuvLVDnBhx34DIv/pub?gid=186097297&single=true&output=csv")
```

#### core capability

```
import shapely.geometry, shapely.ops
import geopandas as gpd
import numpy as np

gdf_sg = gpd.read_file(
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/yinshanyang/singapore/master/maps/0-country.geojson"
)
# Singapore bounday as a shapely multipolygon
sg = gdf_sg.dissolve()["geometry"].values[0]
utm = gdf_sg.estimate_utm_crs()

# restucture rainfall data to be long
# stack() by default dropna=True
df = (
    df_.set_index([c for c in df_.columns if c[0].isalpha()])
    .stack(dropna=False)
    .reset_index()
    .rename(columns={"level_5": "Date", 0: "Rainfall (mm)"})
    .drop(columns=["Station", "Longitude", "Latitude", "Elevation"])
)

df_stations = df_.loc[:, [c for c in df_.columns if c[0].isalpha()]]

# make a grid of boxes covering Singapore
def make_grid(step=500):
    # number of meters
    STEP = step
    a, b, c, d = gdf_sg.to_crs(utm).total_bounds

    # create a grid for Singapore
    gdf_grid = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
        geometry=[
            shapely.geometry.box(minx, miny, maxx, maxy)
            for minx, maxx in zip(np.arange(a, c, STEP), np.arange(a, c, STEP)[1:])
            for miny, maxy in zip(np.arange(b, d, STEP), np.arange(b, d, STEP)[1:])
        ],
        crs=gdf_sg.estimate_utm_crs(),
    )
    return gdf_grid.sjoin(gdf_sg.to_crs(utm)).drop(columns=["index_right", "name"])


# define function for performance testing...
def station_polys(how="boxes", gdf_grid=None, ids=df_stations["id"].tolist()):
    df_stations_ = df_stations.merge(pd.Series(ids, name="id"), on="id")
    if how == "voronoi":
        # generate a voronoi for all weather station points, clipped to Singapore boundary
        gdf_v = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
            geometry=[
                p.intersection(sg)
                for p in shapely.ops.voronoi_diagram(
                    shapely.geometry.MultiPoint(
                        gpd.points_from_xy(
                            df_stations_["Longitude"], df_stations_["Latitude"]
                        ),
                    ),
                ).geoms
            ],
            crs=gdf_sg.crs,
        ).to_crs(utm)

    elif how == "boxes":
        gdf_v = gdf_grid

    # associate voronoi or grid polygons with correct attributes (id)
    gdf_stations = (
        gpd.sjoin_nearest(
            gdf_v,
            gpd.GeoDataFrame(
                df_stations_,
                geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(
                    df_stations_["Longitude"], df_stations_["Latitude"]
                ),
                crs=gdf_sg.crs,
            ).to_crs(utm),
        )
        .drop(columns=["index_right"])
        .dissolve("id")
    )
    return gdf_stations

def polys_for_combis(head=5, how="voronoi", gdf_grid=None):
    # have to be tuples so they are immutable and hashable for join
    # association between Date and combination of station ids
    s_combi = (
        df.dropna()
        .sort_values(["Date", "id"])
        .groupby("Date")["id"]
        .agg(tuple)
        .rename("combi")
    )

    # unique combinations, plus give them an id
    df_combi = pd.DataFrame({"combi": np.unique(s_combi)}).assign(
        combi_id=lambda d: d.index
    )
    # for testing use subset of combinations
    if head is not None:
        df_combi = df_combi.sample(n=head, random_state=44)

    # construct geometry for each combination of stations
    gdf_combi = pd.concat(
        [
            station_polys(how=how, ids=combi, gdf_grid=gdf_grid)
            .reset_index()
            .assign(combi_id=combi_id)
            for combi_id, combi in df_combi.set_index("combi_id")["combi"].iteritems()
        ]
    )

    # add date for combi and join in rainfall data
    gdf_rainfall = gdf_combi.merge(
        df_combi.merge(s_combi.reset_index(), on="combi").drop(columns=["combi"]),
        on="combi_id",
    ).merge(df, on=["id", "Date"])

    return gdf_rainfall
```

#### use it / visualise

```
import folium
from IPython.display import display, HTML

# voronoi or boxes
gdf_rainfall = polys_for_combis(head=10).sort_values("Date")
# gdf_rainfall = polys_for_combis(head=10, how="boxes", gdf_grid=make_grid(step=200)).sort_values("Date")

plot_opts = dict(
    column="Rainfall (mm)",
    height=200,
    width=250,
)

maps = []
for i,d in enumerate(gdf_rainfall["Date"].unique()):
    m = gdf_rainfall.loc[gdf_rainfall["Date"].eq(d)].explore(**plot_opts)
    m.get_root().html.add_child(folium.Element(f"<h5>{d}</h5>"))
    maps.append(m)
    
fmt = '<iframe srcdoc="{}" style="width: {}px; height: {}px; display:inline-block; width: 24%; margin: 0 auto; border: 2px solid black"></iframe>'

rawhtml = ""
for i, m in enumerate(maps):
    # if i>3: break
    rawhtml += fmt.format(m.get_root().render().replace('"', "&quot;"), plot_opts["height"], plot_opts["width"])

display(HTML(rawhtml))
```

` different stations to deal with different NaN on different dates
[image]